# Java SWT autocomplete for Eclipse

Tags: java, swt

I'm manipulating SWT library for Java with Eclipse. It's cool however something is missing. Eclipse doesn't propose any thing concern SWT, Ctrl-Space seems losing its magic. 
I'd like to know if we can add Autocompletation for SWT and Do you know any cool site to learn SWT
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a project that uses SWT, and you'd like to have all the SWT source and Javadoc available while you're coding, you probably want to use the [PDE version of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2). This version comes with all of the source and documentation for all of the SWT, JFace, and Eclipse RCP classes, and provides useful functionality if you are ultimately going to create an RCP application or plug-ins for one.

Answer (score 0):

No auto-completion? That's not supposed to happen. Does your project compile? Do you have the swt.jar in your build path? Does the JDK version work with the SWT version?
Anyway if you want all the documentation, completion etc, if you're using IDE Eclipse, you need both swt.jar and swt.zip - the source. Add swt.jar to build path, tie swt.zip for source and build the project. If still doesn't work try Refresh and build again.